# Laravel Eloquent relationships - user country regions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I am using `Laravel 5.5`. I have a `MySQL` table implementation that contains

Table: `regions`

```
id      name
1       NA
2       SA
3       AP
3       ASEAN
```

The user can create regions and allocate countries to them.

Pivot table: `region_countries`

```
id      region_id     country_id
1       1             1
2       1             2 ....
210     5             1
```

A country can belong to many regions, as the user can create a custom region, by grouping countries.

Table: `countries`

```
id      name ....
1       Argentina....
```

A user belongs to a country, and thus to many regions

Table: `Users`

```
id      name          country_id
1       John Smith    32
```

My `Country` class contains:

```
/**
 * Countries have many Regions
 */
public function regions()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Region::class, RegionCountry::class);
}
```

My `Region` class contains:

```
/**
 * Regions have many Countries
 */
public function countries()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Country::class, RegionCountry::class);
}
```

So for the `User` class relationships, Is this the correct way to do this?

```
/**
 * A User has a Country
 */
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, 'country_id');
}

/**
 * A User has many Regions
 */
public function regions()
{
    return $this->country()->hasMany(Region::class, 'region_id');
}
```

And the reverse, `Region` class has many Users

```
/**
 * Regions have many Countries
 */
public function countries()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Country::class, 'country_id');
}

/**
 * Regions have many Users
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->countries()->hasMany(User::class, 'country_id');
}
```